# Is an expression always positive?

Tags: functions

I have an equation depending on two variables, $k$ and $n$.

$$    f=n(k-1)\log(n)/(n+1)-\log(k) $$

I want to know precisely ALL the combinations for which $f>0$. I can do stuff in Matlab, and I can substitute values in the function. But is there any way that I can know for sure?

Both $n$ and $k$ are variables.

Comment: One way forward is to find all if any zeroes then test the intervals around them, but which of your letters are variables and which are constants?

Comment: Also, are they reals or integers? Anyway, for $n=k=1$, we clearly have $f=0$. And for $n=1$ and $k>1$, $f<0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that $n$ and $k$ are commonly used for integers, and some other vague clues in your post, I assume that you intend that here. However, considering them to be continuous tells much about this function.  Since we are taking logarithms of them both, we also clearly have $n > 0, k > 0$.

Differentiating with respect to $n$,
$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial n} = (k-1)\frac {n+1 + \ln n}{(n+1)^2}$$ and therefore $f$ is increasing when $n+1 > -\ln n$, which is true for all $n \ge 1$.
Hence for each $k$, there is at most one $n_k$ with $f(n_k, k) = 0$. For $n < n_k, f(n,k) < 0$ and for $n > n_k, f(n, k) > 0$.

Differentiating with respect to $k$,
$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial k} = \frac {n\ln n}{n+1} - \frac 1k$$ and therefore for fixed $n$, $f$ is decreasing for $k < \frac{n+1}{n\ln n}$ and is increasing for $k > \frac{n+1}{n\ln n}$.

But $$\begin{align}n = 2 &\implies \frac{n+1}{n\ln n} \approx 2.2\\n = 3 &\implies \frac{n+1}{n\ln n} \approx 1.2\\n \ge 4 &\implies \frac{n+1}{n\ln n} < 1\end{align}$$

Some checking of values shows that $f(n,1) = 0$ for all $k$ while $f(1, k) < 0$ for $k > 1$. Otherwise $f(2,2) < 0$ and $f(2,3)<0$, but $f(2,4) = 0$ and $f(3,2), f(3,3)$ are both $ > 0$. From this, and the fact that $f$ is increasing everywhere else shows that for integer $n, k$,

- $f(n,k) < 0$ for $(n,k) \in \{(2,2), (2,3), (1, k) \mid k > 1\}$.
- $f(n,k) = 0$ for $(n,k) \in \{(2,4), (n,1) \mid n \ge 1\}$.
- $f(n,k) > 0$ for all other $(n,k)$.